# proving limits by ϵ−δ and ϵ−M

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having a real hard time with these two:

1) $$\lim_{x-> ∞}   \frac{x}{x+sinx} = 1$$ -- proving only by using "ϵ−M"

2)$$\lim_{x-> 2} \sqrt{3x-2} = 2$$ -- proving only by using "ϵ−δ"

i have tried both a lot of times, tried to find a connection between δ an sqrt{3x-2} without no luck. i got into messy numbers and i know that i'm missing something. if you could show me the way it would help a lot.
same for the firt one with the sine. I'm lost.

would really appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: For the second one, note that $\sqrt{3x-2}-2 = (\sqrt{3x-2}-\sqrt{4} )\frac{\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{4}} = \frac{3x-2-4}{\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{4}}$.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand.

should i not use the $$\|x-x_0|<δ$$ ? if i combine them how can i calculate the limit?

would appreciate any help to understand it.

Comment: Yes, you should, but if you use the trick above it gets easier. Note that the denominator is in fact bounded from below, so you only need to consider the numerator.

Comment: understood, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>1$ we have

$|\frac{x}{x+sinx} - 1|= \frac{| \sin x |}{x+ \sin x} \le \frac{1}{x+ \sin x} \le \frac{1}{x-1} $.

Your turn !